# Glusterfs can not quota on non-existing directory

Tags: glusterfs

I am using glusterfs 3.7.6.

[The Gluster Documentation](https://gluster.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Directory%20Quota/) says,

> **Note** You can set the disk limit on the directory even if it is not
>   created. The disk limit is enforced immediately after creating that
>   directory.

But, when I try to quota on **non-existing** directory, it fails and shows below message.

```
$ gluster volume quota testVolume limit-usage /quota1 10MB
quota command failed : Failed to get trusted.gfid attribute on path /quota1. Reason : No such file or directory
please enter the path relative to the volume
```

Tested same thing on glusterfs 3.3.2 worked very well.
So I've looked up release note 3.5 through 3.7.1, but couldn't find anything about this.

Is glusterfs 3.7 doesn't support quota on non-existing directory?

Or just something wrong with me?