# Is the limit to the gluster volume size I can create the node's available storage?

Tags: glusterfs

I have 3 nodes in a gluster cluster each with 300G of storage. If I have created only one volume on that cluster, can I write data worth 900G to the volume? The volume is in replica mode on 2 nodes, is is possible for me to write to the volume data that is more than each node's available storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`gluster volume quota name-volum enable`

`gluster volume quota name-volume limit-usage /mnt 10GB`

[Source Setting Limits](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Storage/3.1/html/Administration_Guide/Setting_Limits.html) and [More Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35838271/glusterfs-can-not-quota-on-non-existing-directory)

Comment: I'm not trying to limit the space each volume can take, I want to know whether the volume is limited to the space on the nodes on which it is created and replicated